# Show() Method in DialogFragment not working in android

Tags: android, dialog, show, dialogfragment

I am calling a DialogFragment from inside a DialogFragment. The Show() method from this class is working in a specific situation only. Here is the code:

```
//Not Working
 DialogBoxFragment dialog = new DialogBoxFragment();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putString("selectedLine", "test");
 dialog.setArguments(args);
 android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
 dialog.show(fm,"Dialog");
```

If I comment some lines, than it works:

```
 DialogBoxFragment dialog = new DialogBoxFragment();
// Bundle args = new Bundle();
// args.putString("selectedLine", "test");
// dialog.setArguments(args);
 android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
 dialog.show(fm,"Dialog");
```

Inside the DialogFragmentManager class we have:

private void DeletePhoneNumber(){

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("SmartCall");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(**getArguments().getString("selectedLine")**);
    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

}

Could someone explain why?

Thank you very much in advance.
Leonardo

Comment: Could you post the code relating to what the `DialogBoxFragment` does with the `selectedLine` argument?

Comment: is onCreateDialog in DialogBoxFragment called?

Comment: the code with the commented lines yes, but if I put any code before the Show() method it is seems it is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.
The problem was the method putString(), which I was sending wrong argument, but no error messages was being raised.

Thank you for helping me.
Leonardo